# Plotting Time in hours?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset

```
    Time   Forums_Read
1   00:01   1
2   00:04   1
3   00:05   3
4   00:06   3
5   00:07   3
6   00:08   6
7   00:10   2
8   00:11   2
9   00:12   1
```

I am trying to geom_line the data. However, it needs to be of type POSIXct.
The structure of the column-Time is:

```
Factor w/ 1254 levels "00:01","00:04",..
```

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: that class of dates requires a starting point. You could choose an arbitrary date like the default and chart from there. `as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%M:%S")`. I assumed those are minutes and seconds. Use `"%H:%M"` if not.

Comment: hmm!! interesting! it worked out! thanks a lot! please make an answer so that i choose your best answer! Thanks again.

Comment: Did you read the data in as a factor? Perhaps you can skip the factorization steps by specifying stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date class `POSIXct` requires a starting point. We can use any since the values in the `Time` column are being compared to each other. This function call will convert the dates to the proper format.

```
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%M:%S")
```

I used the format `"%M:%S"` to indicate minutes and seconds. If you have hours and minutes represented in your data, use `"%H:%M"`. For more information on date formatting see `?strptime`.

Comment: Check out lubridate -- it is really useful for managing time datum

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of @Pierre Lafortune's comment,

```
Df$Time2 <- as.POSIXct(
  paste0(Sys.Date(), " 00:", as.character(Df$Time)))
##
library(ggplot2)
##
ggplot(
  data = Df,
  aes(x = Time2, y = Forums_Read)) +
  geom_line()
```

---

[image]

---

**Data:**

```
Df <- read.table(text = "    Time   Forums_Read
  1   00:01   1
  2   00:04   1
  3   00:05   3
  4   00:06   3
  5   00:07   3
  6   00:08   6
  7   00:10   2
  8   00:11   2
  9   00:12   1",
  header = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```